# Are there any alternative than array in JavaScript (for insertion and deletion) to optimize performance

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I am new to JavaScript, I use operations like insertion and deletion of elements. Arrays are not good in insertion and deletion operations. Are there any alternative other than Array in JavaScript to perform these operations? Like we have ArrayList in Java.

```js
function maintest() {
  deletelem(3);
  insertelem(9845568);
 
}

function deletelem( num ) {
  var value = num;
  var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3]
  arr = arr.filter(function(item) {
      return item !== value
  })
  console.log(arr);
}


function insertelem( num ) {
var value = num;

  var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3]

  arr.splice(2, 0, num);
  console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<body onload="maintest()">
  <div id="mainDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: A Java `ArrayList` is basically an array; its performance characteristics are basically exactly the same as a JavaScript array.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, are there any better way to insert and delete elements in java script, I want to improve performance of my application

Answer (score 8):

Arrays are JavaScript's only built-in ordered container type (well, almost; keep reading). There is no "list" in the standard library, though creating one wouldn't be hard; any of the standard "linked list" algorithms is easily implemented in JavaScript. Arrays in JavaScript are inherently sparse, and separately array operations on non-sparse arrays are very fast, so it's not common to find that you need a "list" class specifically.

Depending on your use case, you may find one of these handy:

- An object with named properties, rather than numeric indexes.
- A [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which maps keys to values. Keys and values can be any type.
- A [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which is a *set* of unique values. Values can be of any type.

Other than that, I wouldn't be surprised if a search turned up some prebuilt "list" classes you could use.